# Pandas select n middle rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Suppose I have a dataframe, **df** like this

```
col1 col2 col3
 1     2     34
 11    32    32
 21    62    34
 31    12    31
 13    82    35
 11    32    33
 41    32    33
```

and I want to select 3 rows after first 2 rows, that is I want to select these rows

```
 21    62    34
 31    12    31
 13    82    35
```

How can I do this?

Comment: `df.iloc[2:2+3]`?

Answer (score 22):

Use slicing of rows with `loc` to do that like `df.loc[2:5]`

Output:

```
  col1  col2  col3
2    21    62    34
3    31    12    31
4    13    82    35
5    11    32    33
```

If you want to ignore the current index then use slicing with `iloc` which will get the rows between the range.

```
df.iloc[2:4]
```

```
  col1  col2  col3
2    21    62    34
3    31    12    31
```

Answer (score 4):

You can do `df.iloc[2:4]` or just `df[2:4]`.

Answer (score 1):

Select the first 5 rows then out of 5 top select last 3.

df.head(5).tail(3)

Answer (score -1):

If the table is too big and indexes are too many, you can use this:

```
`a = len(df) / 2
 b = (len(df) / 2) + 3
 df.loc[a : b]`
```